# should passing an object using its reference increase the reference count in a reference counting class

Tags: c++, opencv, reference, pass-by-reference

I am writing a class that uses reference counting to manage its resources.

If the class passed to a function using its reference, should it reference added?

If my object passes to a function via its reference, do I get a copy constructor or any other method on class called?

For example I want to know how it is implemented in a share_pointer or a cv::Mat.

If I pass a cv::Mat into a method using reference, does their reference counter is added?

for example:

```
void func(cv::Mat & image)
{
     // what is the reference counter here? is it one or two?
}

main()
{
     cv::Mat image;
     // reference counter for image should be one here.
     funct(image);
 }
```

Comment: As an excersise, you can try to write a reference-counting class which would track it's passing by reference (or pointer for this matter). Tell us if you succeed.

Answer (score 3):

Typically when a class has a reference count it is storing the number of copies of that object exist.  When you pass an object by reference no copy is made.  The compiler could be using a pointer or it could be using the actual object but it is not making a copy so the reference counter does not increase.

Comment: what about when I have a say vector<cv::Mat>? If I pass a reference to this type of object, does reference count of images are added?

Comment: @mans If you pass the vector by reference then nothing is copied so no reference counts should increase.  A reference count could only increase when the copy constructor or copy assignment operator are called.

Answer (score 3):

Reference counts are generally tracked in the copy constructors, assignment operators and destructor. If you pass by reference then none of those functions are called, so the reference count will remain unchanged.

```
void func(cv::Mat image) //reference count increased due to copy
{

} //reference count decreased due to destruction

void func(cv::Mat& image) //no copy, reference count unchanged
{

} //no destructor call, reference count unchanged
```